# Get the majority from 3 columns of the same row and add the results as a new row

Tags: r

I am trying to get the results from 3 columns and adding the result in the result column under the same row
My data

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ No    CART    RF    XG     Result              ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1      Yes    No    No        No               ║
║ 2      Yes    Yes   No        Yes              ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

How do I get the Result column by looking at CART, RF and XG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer(Self promotion)**: Using [manymodelr](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=manymodelr)(For a more uptodate version, use the developer [version](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr)), we can get the mode rowwise:

```
 df$Res<-apply(df[,-4],1,manymodelr::get_mode)
 df
  No CART  RF XG Result Res
1  1  Yes  No No     No  No
2  2  Yes Yes No    Yes Yes
```

Data:

```
df <-structure(list(No = 1:2, CART = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "Yes", class = "factor"), 
    RF = structure(1:2, .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    XG = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "No", class = "factor"), 
    Result = structure(1:2, .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking the mode function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/3962914),

```
Mode <- function(x) {
   ux <- unique(x)
   ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

we can apply it row-wise using `apply`

```
df$Result <- apply(df[-1], 1, Mode)
df

#  No CART  RF XG Result
#1  1  Yes  No No     No
#2  2  Yes Yes No    Yes
```